# Why does this coroutine generate None values forever?

Tags: python, yield, coroutine

I have a simple coroutine

```
def id():
    while True:
        x = yield
        yield x
```

I can use it to create a generator and prime it with `next`

```
gen = id()
next(gen)

for x in gen:
    print(x)
```

This will print `None` forever. My intuition is that the generator from `id` would only `yield` a value once a value has been `sent` to it, but in this case it's producing `None` values all by itself.

Can someone explain this behaviour to me? Is the `x = yield` statement defaulting `x` to `None`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have pointed out, calling `next(gen)` is equivalent to calling `gen.send(None)`. You can see this if you look at the [C code for generator objects](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/db302b88fdb6/Objects/genobject.c):

```
PyDoc_STRVAR(send_doc,
"send(arg) -> send 'arg' into generator,\n\
return next yielded value or raise StopIteration.");

PyObject *
_PyGen_Send(PyGenObject *gen, PyObject *arg)
{
    return gen_send_ex(gen, arg, 0); 
}
...
static PyObject *
gen_iternext(PyGenObject *gen)
{
    return gen_send_ex(gen, NULL, 0); 
}
```

As you can see, `iternext` (which is what gets called when you call `next(generator_object)`), calls the exact same method as `generator_object.send`, only it always passes in a `NULL` object. Consider that your `for x in gen` loop is basically the equivalent of doing this:

```
iterable = iter(gen):
while True:
    try:
        x = next(iterable)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    print(x)
```

And you see what the issue is.

It's important to realize that coroutines and generators are really completely separate concepts, even though they're both implemented using the `yield` keyword. In general, you shouldn't be iterating over a coroutine, and in general you don't need/want to `send` things into a generator. I highly recommend David Beazley's [PyCon coroutine tutorial](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/) for more on this and coroutines in general.

Answer (score 2):

The `for` statement calls the `next` method of the generator instead of the `send` method. According to the documentation (Python 2.7) this results in the `yield` statement returning None:

> `generator.next()`
>
> Starts the execution of a generator function or
>   resumes it at the last executed `yield` expression. When a generator
>   function is resumed with a `next()` method, the current `yield` expression
>   always evaluates to `None`.

Answer (score 0):

yield is an expression that is only valid inside of functions. The value of a yield expression is None. So your function yields None, then assigns the result of yield (None) to x, then yields x. To demonstrate what is happening better let's yield something from the first yield and see what happens.

```
def id():
    while True:
        x = yield 5
        yield x
```

This will now generate the following sequence:

```
5
None
5
None
5
None
5
None
...
```